# Fixing a Network adapter in a VM

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I have an old Windows server 2008 r2 that was a bare metal server converted to a vhd using Microsoft's Systernals's disk2vhd utility before the server was sunsetted. Fast forward to today, using hypervisor v under Windows 10, the VM comes up just fine except there's no internet connectivity since it has its original configuration. How can I configure this so that I can retrieve some content from the VM?

It is connected to a virtual switch: [image]

I deleted the network elements, rebooted, but now I cannot get the VM to recognize the network adapters. I thought reinstalling the adapter, the networking client (Client for Microsoft Networks), and TCP/IP that it'd come to life. No such luck.

I made a copy of the VM and preserved the original so I'm back to with with a fresh copy since I mucked up the first copy. :)

[image: Network Adapter Properties]

Comment: Is it connected to a virtual switch?

Comment: @Davidw - yes; added image for reference.

Comment: Did you install integration services on your VM?

Comment: Hyper-V was installed a long time ago for another project and not sure if I installed that then. How can I find out?

Comment: What type of virtual switch is it? (external, internal, or private)

Comment: My physical workstation has a Broadcom 802.11 AC.

Comment: Ah, the Virtual Switch type in HyperV: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/virtual-networking-configuration-best-practices/

Comment: It's set to default. I've added an image to my original post for reference. I also added an image of the network adapter of the VM itself which might be what you are asking from me?

Comment: The computer (host) only has one NIC. I read a blog post where the author stated you needed to have two distinct NIC. Is there any validity to that? I assumed the host could share the NIC with the VM but perhaps because the VM is a server it doesn't play as nicely as Ubuntu?

Comment: The virtual switch type is set when you create the switch. In Hyper V manager, select the Virtual Switch Manager in the Actions menu at the top right. Select the Virtual Switch under Virtual Switches at the top left, and at the right, it will show the properties. In order for that virtual switch to communicate with the internet, it must be set to External, and you must select the network adapter that switch communicates via.

Comment: Trying that now

Comment: Using the Switch manager, I created a new entry for External and selected my broadcom NIC. I also updated the VM settings to use the newly created entry. Powered up the VM but still no valid IP.  Running the diagnostic option was useless.

Comment: I also learned today how to share a USB from the host to the guest so I can get the data I need that way. Once on a USB drive, I can copy from there to the network. It's double the effort moving the data but the data is what's ultimately important. If we can't get the IP issue resolved, I have a plan b at least.

Comment: Can you create an address reservation for the MAC Address on the DHCP server, or set a static IP Address on the VM?

Comment: I have the option to do both; I first reserved the mac and tried with no luck. I then tried the static IP with no luck; lastly I tried the combination and still no luck.